# Loss of significance when changing baseline category in regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-encoding

Let's say I am using age group as a factor in a linear regression model with some response variable, fitting the model with under-20s as the baseline category. If there are any significant effects for older age categories when compared with under-20s, I can see this easily through a coefficient whose 95% confidence interval excludes zero.

Let's say now that I set the 20-24 age category as the baseline, but otherwise enter all the same variables into the model. Unlike before, I now have the opportunity to test whether the 25-29 age category differs significantly from the 20-24 category in terms of its effect on the response variable.

My question is: are all my tests - across the two baselines - still being performed individually at the 95% significance level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes, all your tests would typically be performed (you haven't actually said what software platform you're using, so I can't be 100% sure ...) at the 95% significance level.
- If you re-fit the model several times with different baselines, you might want to consider a multiple comparisons correction.
- If you're going to make pairwise comparisons at all you should probably consider using the Tukey all-pairwise-comparisons correction (e.g. see the `multcomp` package in R); this will be less severe/cost you less than the generic correction for $n(n-1)/2$ tests.
- if you want to test for significant differences between successive levels you could use `?contr.sdif` from the `MASS` package.
- in general I think people are over-eager to do significance tests for specific patterns among levels of categorical predictors.  For example, suppose I have a situation where the response increases gradually among the groups "<20", "20-40", ">40", and that the change is gradual and noisy enough that among all pairwise comparisons I can only detect a significant difference between "<20" and ">40". It is true, but probably not very helpful, to say "young and old people are significantly different from each other but neither young nor old people are significantly different from middle-aged people" ... better just to say "there is a significant effect of age - overall, it appears that the response increases with age"

Comment: Thanks very much Ben - that's really helpful. It also answers the specific question that was in my mind, inasmuch as it makes clear that the significance level begins to fall when multiple levels of the same covariate are being compared with each other.